# Is there a way to display hexadecimal representation instead of decimal in IDA pseudocode view?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

Is there a way to display hexadecimal representation instead of decimal in IDA pseudocode view? It's more practical for me to use hexadecimal since my structs are all mapped in hex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In IDA Pro 7.7, there is an option to enable displaying hex as default:

1. Click menu Edit -> Plugins -> Hex Rays Decompiler to open a dialog
2. In the dialog above, click Options in the right-bottom corner
3. Change the `Default radix` to 16

That's all.

By the way, you could press H key to switch between hex and decimal.